# String Manipulation - Jumble Strings C++

Tags: c++, string, function

Hello fellow programmers, I was given a homework assignment to write code that takes a string entered by the user who then chooses how to manipulate the string and in certain cases print it to the console. I have the code mostly written and working but there are a couple functions I don't understand how to write.

One of the options is supposed to take the string and show a "jumbled version" of the string without actually changing it. (eg. "Hello World!" becomes "oleWrl !odlH" or any other random variation each time the option is chosen.)

This is the function I have now and was *not* accepted by my professor because it changes the original string itself.

```
std::string jumbleString(string str2) { //jumble
  string str = str2;
  random_shuffle(str.begin(), str.end());

  return str;
}
```

What is an alternate way I can jumble/shuffle and print a string to get the same results?

edit: Added an actual question

*I apologize for any formatting irregularities, this is my first time posting here. Thank you for any and all help. :) This assignment is driving me nuts.*

Comment: No it doesn't change the original. Your professor is very poorly articulating that they want you to use some form of a loop. Your way is the way most c++ savvy programmers will approach the program, so take comfort in that.

Comment: What @StoryTeller said is very true. Using the standard library's algorithms to replace hand-coded loops is generally very welcome in modern C++ code.

Comment: Having said the above... This is a Q&A site, and your post doesn't actually contain a question.

Comment: I apologize, I meant to ask for an alternate way that I might be able to do this. I was more focused on the formatting lmao @StoryTeller

I do take comfort in what you told me, by the way. Thanks, ha.

Comment: Interesting fun fact: In `std::string jumbleString(string str2)` parameter `str2` is passed by value. [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value) Good question. Read the link and find out. Anyway, this most likely means `str2` is already a copy of the source so `string str = str2;` accomplishes nothing useful. You can safely operate on `str2` throughout the function. Read the above as Your professor has  consumed an excessive amount of crack.

Comment: Question: Are all of the words in the string supposed to be shuffled individually or is the string one big pool to be shuffled?

Comment: @user4581301 As I understand it, it's supposed to be one big pool. Also, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you need to map each character to a new position... so map each original position to a new position:

```
using size_type = std::string::size_type;

std::vector<size_type> pos(str2.length());
size_type n = 0;
std::generate(begin(pos), end(pos), [&]{ return n++; });
std::shuffle(begin(pos), end(pos), std::rand);
for (auto i : pos)
  std::cout << str2[i];
```

Comment: This is extremely helpful, thank you.

Just so I understand what this is doing; it just takes each of the characters in the string and reassigns it to a new position, correct?

Comment: Yup. And then prints it out character by character.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated.